# JQuery KO button not working in mRender function

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

```
{
  sTitle: '', mData: 'id', bSearchable: 'false', bSortable: false, sWidth: '290px',
  mRender: function (data, type, full) {
    return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick =" + self.startResetPassword(full) + "></button>"
    //return "<button type='button' id='ResetPassword' class='btn btn-primary' data-bind='click:{return self.startResetPassword("+full.id+");}'></button>"
    //return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' data-bind='click: " + function () { return self.startResetPassword("+full.id+"); } + "'></button>"
  }
}
```

None of above button functionality working

Answer (score 0):

Placing click handlers like this is not well received, I would recommend to add it using like this:

```
mRender: function (data, type, full) {
    return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-button-id="+full.id+"></button>"
}
...

contentElement.on('click', 'button.btn-primary', function(){
   var elementData = $(this).data('button-id');
   self.startResetPassword(elementData )
});
```

Comment: Problem in your application is self.startResetPassword(full), it will work only if this function would return a valid function name that would be executed on click, function converted to String, but I assume you want to trigger this function with a specific argument on click.